# Oracle indexes on RIGHT JOIN

Tags: oracle, optimization, oracle10g

So I'm having some issues with proper / any use of indexes in Oracle 10g and I'm trying to get a better understanding of how my explain plan ties back to my query so that I can apply indexing properly. When running the following query:

```
  SELECT *   FROM cns cns, cns_valid_status cvs, cns_valid_category cvc  
  WHERE cns.cns_cvs_code = cvs.cvs_code(+)  
  AND cns.cns_cvc_code = cvc.cvc_code(+) 
  and greatest(cns.start_date, nvl(cvs.start_date,'01-JAN-1900'),     nvl(cvc.start_date,'01-JAN-1900')) 
 < least(cns.end_date,nvl(cvs.end_date,'31-DEC-3999'), nvl(cvc.end_date,'31-DEC-3999'))  
 and nvl(cns.end_date,'31-DEC-3999') > TO_DATE(:V_From_Date,'DD-MON-RRRR HH24:MI:SS')
  order by cns.cns_ident,1,2;
```

I'm getting the following explain details:

```
  "PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT"
  "Plan hash value: 3281260492"
  " "
  "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
  "| Id  | Operation                 | Name               | Rows  | Bytes    | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |"
  "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
  "|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT          |                    |    29 | 19604 |  1613   (1)| 00:01:11 |"
  "|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY            |                    |    29 | 19604 |  1613   (1)| 00:01:11 |"
  "|*  2 |   HASH JOIN OUTER         |                    |    29 | 19604 |  1612   (1)| 00:01:11 |"
  "|   3 |    MAT_VIEW ACCESS FULL   | CNS_VALID_CATEGORY |     4 |   280 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
  "|   4 |    VIEW                   |                    |   169K|    97M|  1610   (1)| 00:01:11 |"
  "|*  5 |     FILTER                |                    |       |       |            |          |"
  "|*  6 |      HASH JOIN OUTER      |                    |   169K|    33M|  1610   (1)| 00:01:11 |"
  "|   7 |       MAT_VIEW ACCESS FULL| CNS_VALID_STATUS   |     5 |   310 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |"
  "|*  8 |       MAT_VIEW ACCESS FULL| CNS                |   169K|    23M|  1607   (1)| 00:01:11 |"
  "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
  " "
  "Predicate Information (identified by operation id):"
   "---------------------------------------------------"
 " "
 "   2 - access(""CNS"".""CNS_CVC_CODE""(+)=""CVC"".""CVC_CODE"")"
 "       filter(GREATEST(""CNS"".""START_DATE""(+),NVL(""CVS"".""START_DATE""(+),TO_DATE(' "
 "              1900-01-01 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')),NVL(""CVC"".""START_DATE"",TO_DATE(' "
 "              1900-01-01 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')))<LEAST(""CNS"".""END_DATE""(+),NVL(""CVS"".""E"
 "              ND_DATE""(+),TO_DATE(' 3999-12-31 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd "
 "              hh24:mi:ss')),NVL(""CVC"".""END_DATE"",TO_DATE(' 3999-12-31 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd "
 "              hh24:mi:ss'))))"
 "   5 - filter(NVL(""CNS"".""END_DATE"",TO_DATE(' 3999-12-31 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd "
 "              hh24:mi:ss'))>TO_DATE(:V_FROM_DATE,'DD-MON-RRRR HH24:MI:SS'))"
 "   6 - access(""CNS"".""CNS_CVS_CODE""(+)=""CVS"".""CVS_CODE"")"
 "   8 - filter(""CNS"".""CNS_CVS_CODE""(+) IS NOT NULL)"
```

I can understand that the indexes on my join columns(cns_cvs_code,cns_cvc_code) wouldn't necessarily apply seeing as it's an outer join (or should they?)

Should I create any indexes at all given the circumstances or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it's an outer join, left or right, does not affect whether the query can benefit from indexes or not.

You might benefit from indexes on the cvs.cvs_code and cvc.cvc_code in this case, but if you are joining the majority of rows from two tables together then a hash join will be the most efficient mechanism.

Comment: I tried indexing on the above said columns but the explain plan was the same. It was performing Full Table Scan. Can you please suggest some other way?

Comment: Well one of the problems here is that you're not showing us the actual query. You're presumably querying views, which have a lot of logic in them, including a bunch of stuff about start and end dates. So if you show the actual query, and if the query references views then give the view definition, then maybe you can get more help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding an index on:

```
nvl(cns.end_date, date '3999-12-31')
```

... and use that expression in the query:

```
and nvl(cns.end_date, date '3999-12-31') > TO_DATE(:V_From_Date,'DD-MON-RRRR HH24:MI:SS')
```

If the selectivity of that expression is very high then the index might be used.